# Regular expression in C language detecting non word characters

Tags: c, regex, string

I am trying to create a script to detect "not correct" characters on a username. I think the best solution is to apply regex. I have created a sample script for this purpose but I can not find the correct combination for detecting the "bad/faulty" characters.

Update: The regex expression that I am using I found it on [Wikipedia Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Sample of code:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* stderr, stdout */
#include <string.h> /* stncpy, strncat etc. */
#include <stdlib.h> /* memory allocation, process control etc. */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>

#define tofind "[^A-Za-z0-9_] $" /* Non word characters */ 
#define MAX_USERS 4
#define MAX_CHARACTERS 20

typedef struct rec {
  char users[MAX_USERS][MAX_CHARACTERS];
}TEMPORARY;

int main (void) {
  regex_t regex;
  int reti , i;

  TEMPORARY *ptr_record;

  ptr_record = (TEMPORARY *) malloc (sizeof(TEMPORARY));

  if (ptr_record == NULL) {
    printf("Out of memmory!\nExit!\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  printf("Sizeof users: %li\n",sizeof(*ptr_record).users);

  /* Compile regular expression */
  reti = regcomp(&regex, tofind, REG_EXTENDED);
  if( reti ){ fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); exit(1); }

  for(i = 0; i < MAX_USERS; i++) {
    printf("Enter username[%i]:\n",i);
    scanf( " %[^\n]" , (*ptr_record).users[i] );

    /* Execute regular expression */
    reti = regexec(&regex, (*ptr_record).users[i], 0, NULL, 0);
    if( !reti ){
      puts("Match");
    }
    else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
      puts("No match");
    }
    else{
      regerror(reti, &regex, (*ptr_record).users[i], sizeof((*ptr_record).users));
      fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", (*ptr_record).users[i]);
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  /* Free compiled regular expression if you want to use the regex_t again */
  regfree(&regex);

  for(i = 0; i < MAX_USERS; i++) {
    printf("Username[%i][%s]:\n",i,(*ptr_record).users[i]);
  }

 return 0;

}
```

Update 2: Input and Output of the code:

```
Enter username[0]:
Th@nos
No match
Enter username[1]:
t#est
No match
Enter username[2]:
!anotherT$est
No match
Enter username[3]:
S%mple
No match
Username[0][Th@nos]:
Username[1][t#est]:
Username[2][!anotherT$est]:
Username[3][S%mple]:
```

I thought that all these inputs would be detected by the regular expression and produce a non match.

Comment: And your question is?...

Comment: What regex library are you using?  ISO C (even the most recent version, C11) doesn't have regex support.

Comment: `regerror(reti, &regex, (*ptr_record).users[i], sizeof((*ptr_record).users));` is fishy, the size of the entire `users` array doesn't have much to do with one entry in it

Comment: Update your question to include sample inputs and outputs, and explain how the output you are getting is not what you were expecting

Comment: Your regular expression is apparently designed to match on anything that contains no alphabetic nor numeric chars, *and* ends in a space. Remember that when you're testing it, as `"%$%#%"` will return no-match, but `"%$%#% "` *will* match.

Comment: Why even bother with a regex, when you can do the same thing with a simple `for` loop using `isalnum(x) || x == '_'`

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough so I will update it. The current regex that I am applying can not detect any special not alphabetic or numeric characters. So my question is where am I going wrong? In theory `"[^A-Za-z0-9_] "` should detect non alphabetic characters or numeric characters. But the output it dose not. I will post a sample of input and output.

Comment: I want to say thank you to everyone for their time and effort to assist me. I decided to apply regex on my solution as I wanted to become more familiar with them, since I am planning to use them also in future implementations. Again thank you all for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the specific question: Finally after some experimentation I understood what I was doing wrong. My regex was not correctly defined. So at the specific task that I want to apply, the correct regex would be `"[^A-Za-z0-9_]"` instead of `"[^A-Za-z0-9_] $"`. It works perfectly sample of output:

```
Enter username[0]:
thanos
No match
Enter username[1]:
thanos test
Match
Enter username[2]:
th#no
Match
Enter username[3]:
test
No match
Username[0][thanos]:
Username[1][thanos test]:
Username[2][th#no]:
Username[3][test]:
```